# C++ Linked List: Node inside of another Node

Tags: c++, list, pointers, linked-list, nodes

Is it possible to point to a Node within another Node:

```
struct Node{
    Node my_Node;
    Node *next;
};

int main(){
    Node *practice = new Node;
    practice -> next = &(practice -> my_Node);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code is wrong. You cannot declare a Node (i.e, my_Node) inside itself

Comment: Could I use a typedef to avoid that?

Comment: I think no. In the structure/class, you can only declare a pointer to the struct/class itself.

Comment: Why do you think you need this?  What problem do you imagine it will solve? See: [The XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: For impractical reasons. I just wanted to know what c++ does if this occurs. Is there any other way to have an infinite sequence of classes within classes?

Comment: You can have classes within classes, but not the class within itself.

Comment: You can also have a class with a pointer which points to itself, is that what you want?  `struct Node { Node *next; }; int main() { Node * practice = new Node; practice->next = practice; std::cout << practice->next->next->next->next->next->next->next->next; }`

Comment: Not really, but thank you for answering my question!

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Node{
    Node my_Node; // this is not allowed
    Node *next;
};
```

Because creating a variable of incomplete type is not allowed in c or c++. Because at that point compiler doesn't know what a `Node` type is and how much space is required?

Answer (score 1):

You can not declare a `Node` within `Node`, first it is an *incomplete type* at that point and second it would require infinite space to allow that(*since a Node must contain a Node which must contain a Node etc...*) which is not possible. You can on the other hand have a `Node *` within `Node`.

Comment: If I use a typedef on Node, could I somehow get around that?

Comment: @user3007077: How can you possibly think that typedef will allow you to create an infinite stack of nested nodes?

Comment: @user3007077 that will not help you, like Beta said you can not have an infinite nesting and as Benjamin asks, what problem are you attempting to solve that a pointer to Node won't help?